# coldfusion <cfcontent image issue

Tags: coldfusion

I am creating the xls using below code:

```
SelectImageDetail is the query which fetches the image details from DB.
<cfset LogoName=url.paths.system&"SelectImageDetail.ImgName&"."&SelectImageDetail.FileExt/>
<cfcontent type="application/excel">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline/attachment; filename=RRInvoice.xls">
<cfoutput>
<table width="619" height="1980" >
<tr>
<cfif trim(LogoName) NEQ "" AND FileExists(#LogoName#)>
<td align="right" colspan="2"><IMG SRC="#LogoName#" ALT="" WIDTH=115 HEIGHT=90 BORDER=0>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can get the displayed in the xls in development server but when i access the same by remote (Production), it's not displayed.

Note: I am uploading the image by creating the directory in the server root base .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding what you are trying to do here. Does the html automatically get interpreted by excel?

One thing that appears to not be correct is inline/attachment. I believe you only want to use "inline" or "attachement", not both. They are two different approaches to serving the file up to the browser.

If changing to only have one of those options doesn't work, rule out excel by removing cfcontent/cfheader and just see if the html outputs correctly.

Comment: That is the good approach , I can try it in my local development.

Comment: I am giving the relative path of the image in excel

Comment: Dan Roberts ,Thanks for your time